# Create a new summary task is not even an option?

Tags: 2010

Using Sharepoint 2010 and I have read that I should be able to create summary tasks just like I would in Project.  But when I follow the instructions to create one, the option isnt even there.  Not grayed out, just physically not there.  Is there something I need to do to make this option available?

[image: No summary task?]